rustfmt: disable compound conditional opening curly brace on new line
I have a Rust compound conditional that doesn't fit on one line, like the following. cargo fmt insists on putting the opening curly brace on a new line.
if self.is_condition_a(argument)
    && self.is_condition_b(argument) 
{
    // ...
}

I have a strong dislike for opening curly braces being on a new line and would much rather, for my library, that the curly brace is on the same line as the second conditional.
I have tried playing around with different configurations of brace_style and control_brace_style in rustfmt.toml to no avail. Is there a way I can configure this?

I don't see an option for that.

Wouldn't a brace on the same line mean that parts of the condition are indented and followed immediately by the body which is equally indented? Sounds like it'd be confusing at a glance.

@kmdreko As I mentioned this is my prefernce. Ideally I would configure the standard indent to 2 and line wrap indent to 4, but I can't do that either
